# Post method trow an Preflight not successful response

Tags: 8

Im working with Drupal 8 and Angular.

I want to create a content from angular.

I have the Get method working.

The problem is with the Post method, **I don't know how to configure it.**

With the Rest Ui module, i have this configuration:

[image]

And in the services.yml file I have this one:

```
  cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: []
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: []
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

It works fine for the Get method, but for the POST, it gives me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://drupal.dd:8083/entity/node.
>   Preflight response is not successful task.service.ts:92

The task.service.ts is from my Angular app.

**Questions:**

1) Is the problem from Drupal configuration or from angular? (if is from angular, i will move the post. )

2)Wich on is the correct way to configure Post Method in Drupal?

**Extra info from the method**
[image]

Comment: `allowedMethods: []` means no methods are allowed. So the `OPTIONS` call fails. Add the appropriate methods to that array, clear the cache, it should work

Answer (score 1):

This is the right cors.config configuration:

```
 cors.config:
        enabled: true
        # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
        allowedHeaders: ['*']
        # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
        allowedMethods: ['*']
        # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
        allowedOrigins: ['*']
```